# Effective solution to sync single files between several machines

Tags: sync, cloud, dropbox, sparkleshare

Many cloud syncronization tools (such as SpiderOak, Wuala, Dropbox, SparkleShare and many other) have a one big drawback - you can not syncronize single files such as `~/.vimrc`, `~/.zshrc`, `~/.bashrc` - only folders.
Is there an effective solution to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice tool called [Syncle](https://github.com/rdolgushin/syncle).

It allows to syncronize single files across file system with some folder (for example, managed and syncronized by SpiderOak).
Syncle is wiritten in Python, has command-line interface and simple YAML-based configuration file.

Maybe someone knows better solution?